# User input in swift 2

Tags: swift2

I am a new programmer currently working working my way up the tutorials.
I have been trying to get a user input into my code and every examples I find on the net seem to suggest that this is the correct syntax. Obviously I am doing something wrong :) Xcode reports: "Use of Unresolved indentifier 'input'"
Thanks in advance.

```
import Foundation

var diceRoll = Int(arc4random_uniform(100) + 1)
print("\(diceRoll)")

print("Enter a number between 1 and 100.")

var userinput=input()
let intinput=userinput.toint()

if intinput == diceRoll {print("correct guess")}
  if intinput < diceRoll {print("too low")}
   else if intinput > diceRoll {print("too high")}
```

Comment: Have you downloaded the helpers.swift file from Tutorial 2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import Foundation

var diceRoll = Int(arc4random_uniform(100) + 1)
print("\(diceRoll)")

var i = 0
repeat {
    print("Enter a number between 1 and 100:")

    if let inputString = readLine() {
        if let inputNumber = Int(inputString) {
            i = inputNumber
        }
    }

} while i < 1 || i > 100
/* console output
24
Enter a number between 1 and 100.
0
Enter a number between 1 and 100.
101
Enter a number between 1 and 100.
100
Program ended with exit code: 0
*/
```

.

```
func readLine(stripNewline stripNewline: Bool = default) -> String?
```

> Returns Characters read from standard input through the end of the
>   current line or until EOF is reached, or nil if EOF has already been
>   reached.
>
> If stripNewline is true, newline characters and character combinations
>   will be stripped from the result. This is the default.
>
> Standard input is interpreted as UTF-8. Invalid bytes will be replaced
>   by Unicode replacement characters.